How can I disable verification when importing a js file and receive a request in a service worker?
I connected the service worker.
I need to make a new response, replacing it in the service worker
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
    self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    try {
        const url = new URL(event.request.url);
        const scope = self.registration.scope;

        if(url.pathname.includes('/nk-self/')) {
            console.log('new Request', url.pathname)

            .....
        }
        
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('error', e)
    }
});

Next I create a documentFragment and add it to the page
In the document fragment I add import js file * import {test} from './index.mjs' *
       const fragment = new DocumentFragment();

       const script = document.createElement("script");
       script.type = 'module'
       script.textContent = `
          import {test} from './index.mjs'
       `
       fragment.appendChild(script);
       self.control.run.appendChild(fragment);

I need to receive this request in the service worker and substitute the correct value
I tried to put a catch block in the service worker
try { 


} catch(e) {


}


But this import does not reach the service worker.
And the error appears earlier.
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './index.mjs' does not provide an export named 'test'


I can't intercept this request and override the response.
How can I make sure that any request, even with an error, is sent to the service worker? ?
